# The integer $m$ is odd if and only if there exists $q \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $m = 2q + 1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The integer $m$ is odd if and only if there exists $q \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $m = 2q + 1$.

Proof.

We have to prove both ways.

Suppose $m$ is odd, then by definition of odd number, $m = 2q+1$ for some $q \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Suppose $m = 2q + 1$, then $m$ is not divisible by $2$ so it's odd.

This is the way I proved it but not sure if I did it right. Any help please?

Comment: Sadly, I don't think that's what your instructor wants.

Comment: This is basically a particular case of the uniqueness of the euclidean algorithm.

Comment: Is that actually the definition of odd number?  It could be but I doubt it is.  An odd number is one that isn't divisible by 2.  BTW how do you know 2q+1 isn't divisible by 2?  (And if a number isn't divisible by 2 how do you know it is expressible as 2q+1?)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are assuming what you want to prove.

**Definition.**  An integer $n$ is said to be *even* if there exists an integer $k$ such that $n = 2k$.  An integer that is not even is said to be *odd*.

**Division Algorithm.**  Let $n, d \in \mathbb{Z}$, with $d \neq 0$.  Then there exist integers $q$ (the quotient) and $r$ (the remainder) such that $n = dq + r$, where $0 \leq r < |d|$.

Assume $m$ is odd.  By the Division Algorithm, there exist integers $q$ and $r$, with $0 \leq r < 2$ such that $m = 2q + r$.  There are only two non-negative integers less than $2$.  They are $0$ and $1$.  If $r = 0$, then $m = 2q$, so $m$ is even, contrary to our hypothesis that $m$ is odd.  Hence, $r = 1$.  Therefore, $m = 2q + 1$.

Assume there exists $q \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $m = 2q + 1$.  Since the integers are closed under multiplication, $2q$ is an integer.  Since the integers are closed under addition, $m = 2q + 1$ is an integer.  Observe that
$$m = 2\left(q + \frac{1}{2}\right)$$
Since $q$ is an integer, $q + 1/2$ is not an integer.  Thus, $m \neq 2k$ for some integer $k$.  Hence, $m$ is not even, so it is odd.